# Restarting long tasks in a group after a worker died

Tags: python, celery

I'm using Celery to run groups of thousands of tasks,
where each task takes a few minutes to run.
The code below is my simple drop-in replacement for `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map`:

```
def map(task, data):
    """
    Perform the *task* on *data* in distributed way. Blocks until finished.
    """
    ret = celery_module.group(task.s(val) for val in data).apply_async()
    return ret.get(interval = 0.1)
```

This works like a charm as long as workers never break.
But sometimes it happens that a node dies, taking a few running tasks with it.
What happens then is that all other tasks finish, workers become idle,
but the `get` waits forever for the results from the dead worker.

How to make the dead tasks retry after some timeout?
The tasks are idempotent, I'm not worried at all about duplicate executions.
I've tried toying with `CELERY_ACKS_LATE` and putting timeouts here and there, 
but nothing seemed to remedy this situation.
I feel that I missed something obvious, but can't find what.

Edit: the transport used, both for broker and results, is Redis.

Answer (score 0):

The correct behavior here would be to set timeout and when that dies retry whole `map` task.

Comment: I'm not sure if re-running computations that took a few hours on around a hundred cores because something that would take a few minutes failed is actually "correct behavior"...